# List of parameters as argument for Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, interactive

Let's say, that we have a list of parameters, that we want to use in manipulate, like so:

`parameters={{a,0,5},{b,-1,5}};`

Of corse you could manually copy and paste that into `Manipulate[]`, but in the problem I'm actually solving, you can't do that.

Below is a very simple example and 2 versions of the code, that don't work:

**VERSION 1**

```
plot1=ListPlot@Table[{x,2x+3}+RandomReal[.4,2],{x,-5,5}];
parameters={{a,0,5},{b,-1,5}};

Manipulate@@Join[
    {Show[plot1,Plot[a x + b, {x,-5,5}]]},
    parameters
]
```

**VERSION 2**

```
plot1=ListPlot@Table[{x,2x+3}+RandomReal[.4,2],{x,-5,5}];
parameters={{a,0,5},{b,-1,5}};

Manipulate[
    Show[plot1,Plot[a x + b, {x,-5,5}]],
    Splice@parameters
]
```

And I tied a few more things, but none of them work. How to do it?

Comment: Rather than eyeball a fit, you should use one of the fitting functions, e.g., [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html), [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html), or [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html).

Comment: This was just an example. For fiting I mostly use ```NonlinearModelFit```. But also for fiting ```NonlinearModelFit``` can be very unstble (finding the wrong local RMS minimums). In some cases, like even if you set the initial values quite close, the fit can be completely wrong. In that case doing it manually is probably the best you can (easyly) do.

Comment: Okay, probably another easy way would be to ```Table``` the ```NonlinearModelFit``` for many different initial values of parameters in some ranges, and chose the best one, but it might still be not that stable, and with a lot of parameters, you could only take a few values for each parameter

Comment: If you are having a problem with `NonlinearModelFit` you should post a question showing what you have tried and others might be able to suggest how to overcome the problem.

Comment: I'll ask about it the next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Manipulate` has a [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute, so you have to manually [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) the list with parameters. Furthermore, use [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) to expand the list into a sequence of arguments.

```
Manipulate[Show[plot1, Plot[a x + b, {x, -5, 5}]], 
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ parameters]]
```